# extjs grid poppulating vertically . all datas are being updated in a single column not in rows.if i hardcode the data iys working perfectly

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

if i hardcode the var myData from the response i get from chrome console it is working perfectly.pls help me fastly pls guys . all datas are being updated in a single column not in rows.the values are not being poppulated in any rows instead on a single column

```
Ext.require([ 'Ext.grid.*', 'Ext.data.*', 'Ext.util.*', 'Ext.state.*',
        'Ext.form.*' ]);

Ext.onReady(function() {

    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var bd = Ext.getBody();

    var simple = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {

        frame : true,
        align : 'center',
        renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
        title : 'Simple Form',
        bodyStyle : 'padding:5px 5px 0',
        width : 600,
        fieldDefaults : {
            msgTarget : 'side',
            labelWidth : 75
        },
        defaultType : 'textfield',
        defaults : {
            anchor : '100%'
        },

        items : [ {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            id : 'start',
            fieldLabel : 'StartDate',
            name : 'start',
            allowBlank : false

        }, {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            id : 'end',
            fieldLabel : 'EndDate',
            name : 'end'

        } ],
        buttons : [ {
            text : 'Submit',
            handler : function() {

                var startDate = Ext.getCmp('start').getValue();
                var endDate = Ext.getCmp('end').getValue();

                alert('hu' + startDate);
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url : '/LogHandlers/ProcessLog',
                    method : 'POST',
                    params : {
                        start : startDate,
                        end : endDate
                    },

                    success : function(result, request) {
                    alert('Succesfully added ' + result.responseText);
                        gridGenerate(result, request);
                        alert('Succesfully added ');
                    },
        failure : function(result, request) {
            alert('Error in server' + result.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
        } ]

    });

    function gridGenerate(result, request) {
        alert('Succesfully added sathya ' + result.responseText);





                     Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.CookieProvider'));


                     var myData = result.responseText;

alert("myData"+myData);


                     // create the data store
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    fields: [{
            name : 'Date',
            type : 'string'
        }, {
            name : 'TimeStamp',
            type : 'string'
        }, {
            name : 'type',
            type : 'string'
        }, {
            name : 'Class Name',
            type : 'string'
        }, {
            name : 'Method',
            type : 'string'
        }, {
            name : 'Message',
            type : 'string'
        }
    ]
        ,
    data: myData
});

// create the Grid
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    stateful: true,
    stateId: 'stateGrid',
    columns: [
        {
            header : 'DATE',
            dataIndex : 'Date'
        }, {
            header : 'TIMESTAMP',
            dataIndex : 'TimeStamp'
        }, {
            header : 'TYPE',
            dataIndex : 'type'
        }, {
            header : 'CLASSNAME',
            dataIndex : 'Class Name'
        }, {
            header : 'METHOD',
            dataIndex : 'Method'
        }, {
            header : 'MESSAGE',
            dataIndex : 'Message'
        }
    ],
    height: 350,
    width: 800,
    title: 'Logs',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

});
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `var myData = Ext.decode(result.responseText);`